# SQL firebird dont select rows with 0

Tags: select, firebird

This works fine, except in the results, I don't want the rows where STILL_REQUIRED is 0.

I am using firebird.

```
Select ID, JobID, NAME, ORDERNUM, STARTAFTER, FINISHBEFORE, 
       START_OFFSET_MINS, 
       TOTAL_MINUTES_REQ - 
             (SELECT coalesce(SUM(TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.END_TIME-TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_TIME) / 60, 0) 
              FROM TABLE_PROCESSTIMES 
              WHERE TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.PROCESSID = TABLE_PROCESSES.ID AND TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_DATE <= '24.04.2018'
             ) AS STILL_REQUIRED 
FROM TABLE_PROCESSES 
ORDER BY JOBID, ORDERNUM;
```

[image]

Comment: Just stick the `STILL_REQUIRED` column code in the `WHERE` clause, with `!=0` after...

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but I cant get it working.. please can you copy the text in? Thanks

Comment: Add `HAVING still_required != 0` before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error as below:

Comment: Invalid token

Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to nest it in another select with the appropriate condition:

```
select ID, JobID, NAME, ORDERNUM, STARTAFTER, FINISHBEFORE, START_OFFSET_MINS, STILL_REQUIRED 
from (
    Select ID, JobID, NAME, ORDERNUM, STARTAFTER, FINISHBEFORE, 
           START_OFFSET_MINS, 
           TOTAL_MINUTES_REQ - 
                 (SELECT coalesce(SUM(TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.END_TIME-TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_TIME) / 60, 0) 
                  FROM TABLE_PROCESSTIMES 
                  WHERE TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.PROCESSID = TABLE_PROCESSES.ID AND TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_DATE <= '24.04.2018'
                 ) AS STILL_REQUIRED 
    FROM TABLE_PROCESSES 
    ORDER BY JOBID, ORDERNUM
) a
where still_required <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you move the inline select to the from clause you can add the condition to your where clause without having to nest it in another select.

```
Select TP.ID, 
       TP.JobID, 
       TP.NAME, 
       TP.ORDERNUM, 
       TP.STARTAFTER, 
       TP.FINISHBEFORE, 
       TP.START_OFFSET_MINS, 
       TPT.STILL_REQUIRED 
FROM TABLE_PROCESSES TP,
     (SELECT TP.TOTAL_MINUTES_REQ - COALESCE(SUM(TPT.END_TIME-TPT.START_TIME) / 60, 0) 
              FROM TABLE_PROCESSES TP,
                   TABLE_PROCESSTIMES TPT
              WHERE TPT.PROCESSID =TP.ID 
              AND   TABLE_PROCESSTIMES.START_DATE <= '24.04.2018'
             ) TPT
WHERE TPT.PROCESSID =TP.ID 
AND   TPT. still_required != 0
ORDER BY TP.JOBID, 
         TPORDERNUM;
```